# MySQL Cast operation throws generic error

Tags: mysql, casting

This statement is part of a larger statement but this past is not work. It throws the usual 1064 error. The goal is to parse a string to get at the number that is in the middle of it, then to cast this to an int so that said number can be compared against other id values. This is the failing query

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('remove_this-151-remove_this_too', 'remove_this-', ''), '-remove_this_too', '') as INTEGER);
```

I'm not sure why this type of syntax is not allowed. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do that with:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('remove_this-151-remove_this_too', 'remove_this-', ''), '-remove_this_too', '') as UNSIGNED)
```

-since there's no `INTEGER` modifier for [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) in MySQL, but there are `SIGNED` and `UNSIGNED`